# history -a not working in bash

Tags: bash, command-history

Am I doing something wrong?  I think I'm following the directions in the man page, and it's just not having any effect.

```
[501] $ history | tail
  492  echo 3
  493  echo 4
  494  echo 5
  495  echo 6
  496  echo 7
  497  echo 8
  498  echo 9
  499  echo 10
  500  PS1='[\!] \$ '
  501  history | tail
[502] $ tail ~/.bash_history 
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
echo 5
echo 6
echo 7
echo 8
echo 9
echo 10
[503] $ history -a
[504] $ tail ~/.bash_history 
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
echo 5
echo 6
echo 7
echo 8
echo 9
echo 10
[505] $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[506] $
```

Shouldn't the output of the command `tail ~/.bash_history` be different the second time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems this is something Apple-specific.  (I'm using Mac OS 10.11.6 El Capitan.)

My `HISTFILE` value is the immediate cause:

```
[512] $ echo $HISTFILE
/Users/Wildcard/.bash_sessions/8BC6B122-0D74-445B-B6A0-7D4D446598CB.historynew
```

But since I don't set that variable, where is it being set?

Aha, it's in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`.  And from the comments there, it looks like I only ran into this because I tried `history -a` by itself, without ever setting `shopt -s histappend`.  They've coded it so that if you turn on histappend, or set the HISTTIMEFORMAT variable, they skip the session resume support code.

Here's the inline documentation for that section:

```
# Resume Support: Save/Restore Shell State
#
# Terminal assigns each terminal session a unique identifier and
# communicates it via the TERM_SESSION_ID environment variable so that
# programs running in a terminal can save/restore application-specific
# state when quitting and restarting Terminal with Resume enabled.
#
# The following code defines a shell save/restore mechanism. Users can
# add custom state by defining a shell_session_save_user_state function
# that writes restoration commands to the session file at exit. e.g.,
# to save a variable:
#
#   shell_session_save_user_state() { echo MY_VAR="'$MY_VAR'" >> "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE"; }
#
# During shell startup the session file is executed. Old files are
# periodically deleted.
#
# The default behavior arranges to save and restore the bash command
# history independently for each restored terminal session. It also
# merges commands into the global history for new sessions. Because
# of this it is recommended that you set HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE to
# larger values.
#
# You may disable this behavior and share a single history by setting
# SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY to 0. There are some common user customizations
# that arrange to share new commands among running shells by
# manipulating the history at each prompt, and they typically include
# 'shopt -s histappend'; therefore, if the histappend shell option is
# enabled, per-session history is disabled by default. You may
# explicitly enable it by setting SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY to 1.
#
# The implementation of per-session command histories in combination
# with a shared global command history is incompatible with the
# HISTTIMEFORMAT variable--the timestamps are applied inconsistently
# to different parts of the history; therefore, if HISTTIMEFORMAT is
# defined, per-session history is disabled by default.
#
# Note that this uses PROMPT_COMMAND to enable per-session history
# the first time for each new session. If you customize PROMPT_COMMAND
# be sure to include the previous value. e.g.,
#
#   PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }your_code_here"
#
# Otherwise, the per-session history won't take effect until the first
# restore.
#
# The save/restore mechanism is disabled if the following file exists:
#
#   ~/.bash_sessions_disable
```

Comment: I'm on a mac, and `history -a` has no effect, but this isn't why. Running `shopt -s histappend` doesn't fix it for me.

Comment: @BenWheeler did you run that command in your bash profile or bashrc, and start a new shell?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me! Note that I had to really start a new shell -- running `source ~/.bash_profile` to reload my bash profile wasn't enough. Thanks!