# where is the history of the current terminal window saved?

Tags: bash, terminal, command-history

I understand that command line history in the case of bash is saved in `.bash_history`.

When you open a terminal emulator window in Ubuntu/MacOS and work in it, the history is not saved in `.bash_history` yet but when you close the window, the history of the session will be appended to the end of the `.bash_history` file.

My question is: where are the history saved during the session, before I close the emulator window?

The reason I care is that sometimes I mess up wile working in it and the terminal window simply freeze. When I force close it, I lose all the history contained in the session.  I want to be able to retrieve them.

Comment: @mosvy, not on MacOS.  It's more complicated there.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/473581/135943

Comment: So, what's the value of `PROMPT_COMMAND` in bash on MacOS? I guess they may be already calling `history -a` from it, in which case the OP can retrieve the history of recently crashed sessions from `ls -t ~/.bash_sessions/ | head`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the suggestions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows), addition to your `.bashrc` is immediate, although there are some disadvantages.

I added the following to `~.bashrc` and have experienced no real issues

```
HISTSIZE=5000
HISTFILESIZE=10000
shopt -s histappend

export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Whether this works in `MacOS` or not I don't know